# iOS local file access and webkit

Tags: ios, webkit

I'm absolutely new to iOS App development (I haven't actually started yet, still in a design phase).
The task that I have to accomplish with my app is to download a zip from somewhere, extract anywere to local storage and display its content (html pages with javascript) in a embed webkit widget.

The questions are:
1) Will my app have access to any folder of my iPad storage memory?
2) Will my app's embedded Webkit widget be able to display local html pages (like file:///somewhere/over/the/rainbow.html ?
3) WIll that local page be able to use Ajax method (over httpxmlrequest) to dynamically load external scripts or xml (also locally stored - ie ./something.xml)?

Thank in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No it can't access *any* file. Apps are sandboxed on iOS. You can only access the app bundle's content and documents folder (a writable area unique to your app).
2. Yes - provided said content is in the areas mentioned in (1). This is how Phonegap-based apps work.
3. Yes - they can. We've done exactly this extensively in several of our apps.

Comment: Great thanks for your answer! Actually my English is not perfect... I meant exactly what you wrote in point 1 with the misused word "any" :)